# Sencha touch 2.0 many-to-many associations - how?

Tags: database, touch, extjs

I've been having a hell of a time getting Sencha Touch 2.0 hasMany associations working, especially since it looks like their data models don't directly allow for many-to-many relationships. I've got two models - People and Roles (theere are a bunch more, but these are the two that matter in this example) , each has a many-to-many to the other.

I originally thought that I could do this with a hasMany in each of the models, but snce  the data is stored in third-normal form in my db, I figure that I need a third, person-to-role model. Code is here:

```
Ext.define('SMToolkit.model.Person', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
            'id',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'address',
            'phone1',
            'phone2',
            'type',
            'location'
        ],
        hasMany: [
            {
                model: 'SMToolkit.model.Person_Role',
                name: 'role'
            }
        ],
        proxy: {
            type: 'rest',
            url : 'index.php/api/persons'
        }
    }

});


Ext.define('SMToolkit.model.Role', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config: {
        fields: [
            'id',
            'name',
            'description',
            'type',
            'show_id'
        ],
        hasMany: [
            {
                model: 'SMToolkit.model.Person_Role',
                name: 'person'
            },
            {
                model: 'SMToolkit.model.Scene_Role',
                name: 'scene'
            },
            {
                model: 'SMToolkit.model.Thing',
                name: 'thing'
            }
        ],
        proxy: {
            type: 'rest',
            url : 'index.php/api/roles'
        }
    }
});


Ext.define('SMToolkit.model.Person_Role', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

config: {
    fields: [
        'person_id',
        'role_id'
    ],
    associations: [
        {
            type: 'belongsTo',
            model: 'SMToolkit.model.Person',
            name: 'person'
        },
        {
            type: 'belongsTo',
            model: 'SMToolkit.model.Role',
            name: 'role'
        },
    ],
    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url : 'index.php/api/personsroles'
    }
}

});
```

I've confirmed that the personsroles url above does in fact return a valid data set, so I know that there should be something in there...

When I look at a Role record, I can see fields for the associated stores, but even if I know for certain that there's an appropriate record in the Person_Role table in the db, the Persons array in the record is empty.

I'm getting the record like so:

```
onRoleSelect: function(list, index, node, record) {
    var editButton = this.getEditButton();
    if (!this.showRole) {
        this.showRole = Ext.create('SMToolkit.view.role.Show');
    }
    person = record.person();
    thing = record.thing();
    scene = record.scene();
    person.load();
    thing.load();
    scene.load();
    // Bind the record onto the view
    this.showRole.setRecord(record);

    // Push the show show view into the navigation view
    this.getRoleContainer().push(this.showRole);
},
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is there no association data?

Comment: To further complicate the matter, even if I could get the person associatin above, it would just give me the record in Person_Role and I don't know how to traverse from there to the actual person record

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative approach for handling complex model relations in Sencha.
I've not yet tested it but I think it will likely handle Many-Many relations as well.
Recursive M-M relations might cause you grief with the linkChildAssociations() function.

- http://appointsolutions.com/2012/07/using-model-associations-in-sencha-touch-2-and-ext-js-4/